# 'str' object has no attribute 'hist' error while calling a function to plot histogram

Tags: python, function

Creating a function by passing the dataframe and columns as the arguments to plot a histogram. But, getting 'str' object has no attribute 'hist' error while calling this function

```
def histogram1(df,c1,c2):
    plot= df.hist(column='c1', by='c2',bins=25, grid=False, figsize=(20,5), layout=(1,2), sharex=True, color='#86bf91', zorder=2, rwidth=0.9)
    for i,x in enumerate(plot):
        x.set_xlabel('c1', labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
        x.set_ylabel('Frequency', labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
    return
```

```
histogram1('dataset','avg_glucose_level','stroke')
```

Comment: check your df variable content it should bea pandas dataframe not a string

Comment: It is a pandas dataframe      
  ```    
   dataset=pd.read_csv('https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/4402679', delimiter='\t')                                                                                                                         ```